# Installing Magento 1.5.1 with previous 1.5.1 SQL export gives a PDOException 23000

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, installation, magento-1.5

Like the title says, I have a previous Magento install of 1.5.1. I'm moving it. I took an export and imported it into the db on a different server. I re-uploaded a magento 1.5.1. I'm trying to run the install and point it to the new db but I keep getting this error. Below in a screenshot of the error taken before it redirects to the magento error page. I'm not a backend programmer and I have little Magento experience so any help would be beneficial.

[image]

Comment: If the text is too small (I didn't realize there wasn't a popup up on images) I can upload a move zoomed in version.

Comment: If you're copying a full site on a different server (source + SQL), you shouldn't have any need to run the magento install again.

Comment: I just copied the DB. Exported the DB and re-imported on a different server's DB and then ran a new install. Basically I want a fresh install with the same old data.

Answer (score 0):

I think on changing db, the magento tries to upgrade the database to 1.5.1 and added a constraint but your old data has duplicate increment Id in sales_flat_order table, that is why you are getting this error.

This issue is discussed here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/221281/

Thanks

Comment: The previous and current version are both 1.5.1. Would this still apply?